# Scrolling text in Crouton Library

Tags: java, android, marquee, crouton

The crouton library can be found [on Github](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton)
And my question is if it's possible how to make the text displayed in the Crouton scrolling horizontally. In a TextView it can be done like this:

```
android:singleLine="true" 
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

But is this also possible in a Crouton? 
I appreciate every help/answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a custom View to Crouton via `Crouton.show(Activity, View)` and it's equivalent `Crouton.make(...)` methods.

You custom View can also be a View that can marquee forever.

Comment: Thanks!!

Danke :)
Grüße aus Österreich